# How to use Mask to hide a specific object?

Tags: masking

In this scene, I want the blue disk to be invisible to the camera, hide the part of text that disk covers while keeping the plane all visible.[image]

Comment: Also see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32032/mask-out-certain-objects and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24169/using-an-object-as-a-clipping-mask-for-another-object?lq=1