# How to make object visible only inside another object?

Tags: animation, modifiers, eevee-render-engine, visibility

I am not such an expert, but also not completely noob and want to make animation like in this template: https://www.storyblocks.com/video/stock/new-business-corporate-promo-hl-kj1ijhk2tf55tw And want to make it in Blender

I already learned how to make radial sweep animation in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUauJWWLqFI (very simple) and had success to make it be rectangle shape with help of this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109005/46872

To not be completely spammer with links, below is result:

Whole procedure:

1. I created a plane, deleted 3 edges, left 1 edge and added screw modifier to this new object (to edge) so I can animate it like radial sweep:

[image]

2. I added the cube with hole in center. I set Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display As > Wire for this cube and unchecked Visibility > Renders.

[image]

[image]

3. I want that Plane (i.e. Edge with screw modifier) be visible only in region of cube body. I want it to be invisible as outside of cube, also in hole in center of cube.

As you can see on below screenshot, I had success only with invisibility outside of cube. Plane (i.e. Edge with screw modifier) is still visible through hole in cube center and I don't want it. Btw, material of Plane is also on below screenshot:

[image]

One more thing: I suppose there is maybe more simple way to accomplish my target - animation from linked video at the beginning of post, but as said, I'm not an expert, had no other idea and was started this way.

Please let me know if any additional info is needed and thanks in advance.

Comment: @Frederik 's trick seems really nice..  but all the references you point to are in post? Any reason to want to do this by shading in 3D, rather than using the compositor on the rendered image?

Comment: related, the opposite of it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173100/19156

Comment: @Robin Betts: Because I never used compositor (beginner). As said in my question: " I suppose there is maybe more simple way....."

Comment: @lemon: I'm trying this in Eevee.

Comment: @stiw47, I know, the answer from Frederik is also for Cycles as Eevee does not provide most of the light paths.

Comment: What do you want to be displayed outside of the cube and in its hole? Nothing?

Comment: @lemon: yes, nothing outside of cube and in hole. I want that radial sweep be displayed only through cube body.

Answer (score 5):

You can make parts of objects invisible using multiple tricks. Since your mesh is animated, it's probably not the easiest animating your material as well. As I get it, if you want to change the animation speed, you need to adjust the material separately. Anyways, here's how I would do it:

[image] 
The sphere simply has a transparent shader set to blueish nothing else.
The cube is only visible if a ray has passed through a transparent shader. I guess you can also invert the sphere (animiation) and use a simple holdout shader on it, but I'm guessing that doesn't work for you for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this not doing job. I think my post wasn't written clear enough on first and sorry for that. I just updated post, hope that my goal is more clear now.

Comment: just switch the inputs of the mix shader. You can build any constructs of masks this way. Need another hole? model it make it transparent put it where you need it.

Answer (score 2):

My deepest apologize to all - my above question can be deleted if this is possible, cause I caught the goal in totally different way. Much simple (almost stupid) way, not sure why didn't try before (probably because I am a n00b :) ).

I simple added Boolean modifier to Plane (Edge with screw modifier) and choose Method: Intersect, Object: Cube.

[image]

This is the result I wanted:

[image]

Sorry once again and thanks to all.

Comment: Hello :). Glad you solved it. You can add relevant hashtags to your question, so it's easier to find. That way, it can be helpful to others with a similar problem.

Comment: Hi Jachym. I added #modifiers and #visibility and removed #materials. If you have some more suggestion...